Using Moq with a template method
I am trying to Moq a Rabbit MQ method.
ValueTask BasicPublishAsync<TProperties>(string exchange, string routingKey,
    bool mandatory, TProperties basicProperties, ReadOnlyMemory<byte> body,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    where TProperties : IReadOnlyBasicProperties, IAmqpHeader;

What is the correct form of:
mockRabbitModel.Setup(a => a.BasicPublishAsync<It.IsSubtype<IAmqpHeader>>(
    It.IsAny<string>() /*exchange*/,
    It.IsAny<string>() /*routingKey*/,
    It.IsAny<bool>() /* mandatory*/,
    // ??????,
    It.Is<ReadOnlyMemory<byte>>(b =>
        this.TestSentMessage(b, (expected, actual) => 
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual.Command))),
    It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()));

Moq can't work with TProperties directly and I have seen various ideas for mapping the argument with ??????

Have you tried to use there It.IsSubtype<IAmqpHeader>? Or simply just It.IsAnyType?

It.IsSubtype<IAmqpHeader> gives me 'It.IsSubtype<IAmqpHeader>' is a type, which is not valid. Wrapping that in an It.IsAny gives me   The type 'System.Func<Moq.It.IsSubtype<RabbitMQ.Client.IAmqpHeader>>' cannot be used as type parameter 'TProperties' in the generic type or method 'IChannel.BasicPublishAsync<TProperties>(string, string, bool, TProperties, ReadOnlyMemory<byte>, CancellationToken)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'System.Func<Moq.It.IsSubtype<RabbitMQ.Client.IAmqpHeader>>' to 'RabbitMQ.Client.IReadOnlyBasicProperties'

It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType> gives us ````The type 'System.Func<Moq.It.IsAnyType>' cannot be used as type parameter 'TProperties' in the generic type or method 'IChannel.BasicPublishAsync(string, string, bool, TProperties, ReadOnlyMemory, CancellationToken)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'System.Func<Moq.It.IsAnyType>' to 'RabbitMQ.Client.IReadOnlyBasicProperties'.


The error messages says that you should use a generic parameter for the IsSubtype which implements both IAmqpHeader and IReadOnlyBasicProperties interfaces.

As you have used It.IsSubtype<IAmqpHeader> as the generic parameter for the BasicPublishAsync, you should use the same type for the basicProperties wrapped into a It.IsAny.
Here is a simplified version of your code:
public interface IFoo
{
    ValueTask BasicPublishAsync<TProperties>(string key1, TProperties properties);
}

Then the mocking should be done like this:
var foo_mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
foo_mock.Setup(foo => foo.BasicPublishAsync<It.IsSubtype<int>>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<It.IsSubtype<int>>()))
        .Returns(() => ValueTask.FromException(new Exception("BlahBlah")));

Here you can find a working sample code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zSEE5D

UPDATE #1
To tackle the multi interface constraint you can introduce a custom TypeMatcher:
The interfaces:
public interface IFoo
{
    ValueTask BasicPublishAsync<TProperties>(string key1, TProperties properties) where TProperties: IA, IB;
}


public interface IA {}
public interface IB {}
internal interface IAB: IA, IB {} // just for testing

The type matcher
[TypeMatcher]
public class FooTypeMatcher<T> : IA, IB, ITypeMatcher
    where T : IA, IB
{
    bool ITypeMatcher.Matches(Type typeArgument)
    {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeArgument);
    }
}

The mock setup:
var foo_mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
foo_mock.Setup(foo => foo.BasicPublishAsync<FooTypeMatcher<IAB>>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<FooTypeMatcher<IAB>>()))
        .Returns(() => ValueTask.FromException(new Exception("BlahBlah")));

Here you can find a working sample code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5kOz8W

Hi -this doesn't work at all as an int has nothing to do with it! The problem is TProperties is only defined in the context of the function and they are all interfaces BasicPublishAsync is not my function but that of a third party library. I can't use any of TProperties IReadOnlyBasicProperties, IAmqpHeader in the type inside the IsAny

@MCFH I've updated my post to address your concern, please revisit again.

thank you - that looks promising! will try it later and report back.

So I now get the following error error CS0311: The type 'RabbitMQ.Client.IAmqpHeader' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'RabbbitPublishTypeMatcher<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'RabbitMQ.Client.IAmqpHeader' to 'RabbitMQ.Client.IReadOnlyBasicProperties'. I assume as the two types are completely unrelated

@MCFH If you could share all the related code fragments, later I can take a look at it.

ok so using     [TypeMatcher]     class RabbbitPublishTypeMatcher : ITypeMatcher, IReadOnlyBasicProperties, IAmqpHeader solved it. THank you for your help

@MCFH Awesome  if you have found my post useful please consider to upvote and / or accept it as the answer
